# Standard practice for treating derived members in a derived class

Tags: c#, properties, derived-class

I have a base and derived class called Node which form elements of a Graph.
I'd like to define a DerivedGraph that can only store DerivedNodes and may have some DerivedNode specific Methods. The Nodes must be mutable in both classes.

What is the standard practice for dealing with this?
Duplicating data members is clearly to be avoided.
Should it be done by type checking and casting within the properties?

```
public class Node {}
public class DerivedNode : public Node {}

public class Graph 
{

    private List<Node> nodes;

    //some code
}

class DerivedGraph : Graph {}
```

EDIT:

I should add I need the functionality that Graph can contain both Nodes and DerivedNodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the use of [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to solve this problem.

```
public class Node {}
public class DerivedNode : public Node {}

public class Graph<T> where T : Node
{

    private List<T> nodes;

    //some code
}

class DerivedGraph : Graph<DerivedNode> {}
```

This would allow you to specify either `Node` or `DerivedNode` when instantiating the class.

Comment: You need a constraint on T being a Node object

Comment: @Michael Will I still be able to have a Graph containing Nodes and DerivedNodes?

Comment: @gwizardry Yes, `Graph` could contain `Nodes` or `DerivedNodes`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a generic Graph and extension methods for Graph where T: DerivedNode? Note: Just came into my mind, haven't done this yet. But this could work and keep your code clean.

You could just make Graph generic and inherit from Graph. So you won't hassle with extension methods

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it, is to use a generic `Graph` class, and then add [constraints on its typed parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to make sure it is `Node` or derives from `Node`:

```
public class Node {}
public class DerivedNode :  Node {}

public class Graph<T : Node>  // <<===
{
    private List<T> nodes;
    //some code
}

class DerivedGraph : Graph<DerivedNode> {}
```

Comment: Haven't seen <T : Node> syntax before is this the same as where T : Node?

Answer (score 0):

You could generics; something like

```
public class Graph<T> where T : Node 
{

    private List<T> nodes;

    //some code
}

class DerivedGraph : Graph<DerivedNode> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
public class Node
{
}

public class DerivedNode : Node
{
}

public class Graph<T>
    where T : Node
{
    private List<T> nodes;

    //some code
}

public class DerivedGraph : Graph<DerivedNode>
{
}
```